# How to get textarea content properly?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, textarea

I'm doing a text to binary converter in form of a browser extension. I have this form:

```
<textarea id="in"></textarea>
<textarea id="out" readonly></textarea>
<div id="buttons">
  <button id="convert">Convert</button>
  <button id="copy">Copy</button>
</div>
```

I want to insert the converted text from the first textarea into the second textarea. This is the script:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", click());
};

function click() {

  // Getting the first textarea value

  var inputText = document.getElementById("in").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  // Testing if it's a binary or a text

  if (/^[0-1 ]*$/.test(inputText)) {
    output.value = binToText(inputText);
  }
  else {
    output.value = textToBin(inputText);
  }

}
```

The problem is if I write into the first textarea, its value does not change, so the `value` property returns null. And the second textarea doesn't show anything.

I tried everything, but it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not binding the event handler correctly. Nothing actually happens when you click the button.

You have to pass the function itself to `addEventListener`, not its return value:

```
document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", click);
//                                                           ^^^^^
```